# React Native Barcode Scanner Mask

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to create barcode scanning mask with rounded corners. Do u have any idea how can I get rid off this corners in the pucture? Much thx

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3mkg.jpg

```
      <RNCamera
        ref={ref => this.camera = ref}
        style={styles.preview}
      >
        <View style={styles.overlay} />
        <View style={styles.contentRow}>
          <View style={styles.overlay} />
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <View style={styles.scanline} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.overlay} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.overlay} />
      </RNCamera>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  overlay: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
  },
  contentRow: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  content: {
    width: 200,
    height: 240,
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderWidth: 2,
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at how I implement it in this library: https://github.com/nartc/react-native-barcode-mask 

Basically, it's going to be 4 different corners with position related to the corner's thickness (borderWidth)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do the same by making something like this:

```
const CaptureBox = () => (
  <View testID="capture-box-container" style={styles.captureBox}>
    <View testID="top-left-corner" style={styles.topLeft} />
    <View testID="top-right-corner" style={styles.topRight} />
    <View testID="bottom-right-corner" style={styles.bottomRight} />
    <View testID="bottom-left-corner" style={styles.bottomLeft} />
  </View>
)
```

And the styling:

```
import { StyleSheet, ViewStyle } from 'react-native'

const edge: ViewStyle = {
  borderColor: 'white',
  borderLeftWidth: 3,
  borderTopWidth: 3,
  borderTopLeftRadius:10,
  position: 'absolute',
  height: 50,
  width: 44,
}

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bottomRight: {
    transform: [{ rotate: '180deg' }],
    ...edge,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  bottomLeft: {
    transform: [{ rotateX: '180deg' }],
    ...edge,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
  },
  captureBox: {
    height: 240,
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  topLeft: {
    ...edge,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
  },
  topRight: {
    transform: [{ rotateY: '180deg' }],
    ...edge,
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
})
```

Otherwise, you will see the background color for the container you are wrapping the edges.

Comment: it has the same  'pieces' without the bg color, as i mentioned in screenshot